# Uncaught TypeError: Web3 is not a constructor

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, blockchain, javascript

I'm trying to create my first to-do app on the blockchain using solidity.

I'm following this tutorial [Build Your First Blockchain Todo List](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=coQ5dg8wM2o)

However, I'm getting this error when I get to this step (45:00)
[image]

I'm running truffle: Truffle v5.0.2 and have web3 installed [image]

My metamask is also connected to my local gaunache blockchain
[image]

I would paste my code here but this error is being thrown from the truffle-contract.js (not my app.js)

Let me know what other information is needed and I will happily provide it. I'm new to blockchain development but haven't found any online help regarding this specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments under the video there is a guy talking about known issues. I was doing the same tutorial when I fist started and had similar problems:
[image: index.html did not work initially for me as Web3 was undefined. To fix this you need to npm install web3 version 0.20.7 and then include it in the index.html file before the truffle-contract.js line i.e. add the following line:]

Comment: Awesome. This was driving me crazy and I appreciate it.